# Marked returns wrong html for a list item with nested list and a paragraph

Tags: javascript, markdown, javascript-marked

When trying to convert this simple markdown to html:

```
* section one
    * item one
    * item two

    This is the first section

* section two
    * item one
    * item two

    This is the second section
```

The html I receive back is:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <p>section one</p>
        <ul>
            <li>item one</li>
            <li>
                <p>item two</p>
                <p>This is the first section</p>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <p>section two</p>
        <ul>
            <li>item one</li>
            <li>
                <p>item two</p>
                <p>This is the second section</p>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

The paragraphs inside the first level list are part of the 2nd list item of the nested list.
I would expect this paragraph to be a sibling of the nested list, I even tested it in different online editors and they render it as I expected and not like the result from `marked`.

Am I doing something wrong or is it a bug in `marked`?
I tried playing around with the options but nothing helped.

Here's the code:

```
const marked = require("marked");
let str = "* section one\n\t* item one\n\t* item two\n\n\tThis is the first section";
str += "\n\n* section two\n\t* item one\n\t* item two\n\n\tThis is the second section";

marked(str)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is definitely a bug. As you noticed, [other implementations](http://johnmacfarlane.net/babelmark2/?normalize=1&text=*+section+one%0A++++*+item+one%0A++++*+item+two%0A%0A++++This+is+the+first+section%0A%0A*+section+two%0A++++*+item+one%0A++++*+item+two%0A%0A++++This+is+the+second+section) render as you expected.

However, it could be argued there is a slight error in your document. You should be adding a line between the first line of your (outer) list item and the nested list.

Suppose you were creating a document which only contained the content of the first (outer) list item. As you have the list formatted, that would look like this:

```
section one
* item one
* item two

This is the first section
```

Which most Markdown implementations [interpret](http://johnmacfarlane.net/babelmark2/?normalize=1&text=section+one%0A*+item+one%0A*+item+two%0A%0AThis+is+the+first+section) at one of:

```
<p>section one * item one * item two</p>
<p>This is the first section</p>
```

or

```
<p>section one <em> item one </em> item two</p>
<p>This is the first section</p>
```

Of course, you need a blank line between the first line and the list. Like this:

```
section one

* item one
* item two

This is the first section
```

Which consistently [renders](http://johnmacfarlane.net/babelmark2/?normalize=1&text=section+one%0A%0A*+item+one%0A*+item+two%0A%0AThis+is+the+first+section) as:

```
<p>section one</p>
<ul>
    <li>item one</li>
    <li>item two</li>
</ul>
<p>This is the first section</p>
```

Apply that to your full document, like this:

```
* section one

    * item one
    * item two

    This is the first section

* section two

    * item one
    * item two

    This is the second section
```

<del>and you get good, consistent [results](http://johnmacfarlane.net/babelmark2/?normalize=1&text=*+section+one%0A%0A++++*+item+one%0A++++*+item+two%0A%0A++++This+is+the+first+section%0A%0A*+section+two%0A%0A++++*+item+one%0A++++*+item+two%0A%0A++++This+is+the+second+section):</del>

Hmm, well, it turns out Marked gets that wrong too. Definitely a bug.

Comment: Thanks.  I opened a [new issue](https://github.com/chjj/marked/issues/789), let's see what they say.